# Contactlist actionlike buttons

Tags: iphone, email, ios, uitableview, location

Don't know on how to ask this in another way, so here it goes!

This is what I want; 
When you view the details of a contact, you have the option of direct calling the phonenumber, send an email or lookup someones address within the Maps App of the iPhone.

I am also creating an App which shows some detailed information about a location. 
The information shown in the detailed view:

- Phonenumber (when choosing this it needs to call the number)
- Emailaddress (when choosing this it needs to open the emailapp)
- Address (When choosing this it needs to open the default MapApp of the iPhone)

Do I achieve this with actions which are available (somewhere)? If so, can anyone point me in the right direction?

I would help me alot!

With kind regards,

Douwe

Answer (score 0):

iOS uses url schemes to allow communication between apps.  You'd need to implement openURL:"yourformattedurlhere" in your button clicks with a properly formed URL to send data to the appropriate app.

You can check Apple's [URL Scheme Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899) for the details on the formatting.